# DataFlow Apache Beam Java JdbcIO Read arguments issue

Tags: java, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am totally new to Apache Beam and Java. 
Been working on PHP for around 5 years but i haven't worked in Java for the last 5 years :), plus Apache Beam SDK in java is something that is also new so bear with me.
I would like to implement pipeline where i will get data from Google PubSub, map the relevant fields into array and then check it to MySql Db to see if the message belong to one table, after that i will need to send api call to our API that will update some data in our app db. Another pipeline will enrich the data from elasticsearch and insert it into BigQuery.

But as of this moment i am stuck with reading data from MySql, i simply cannot adopt the argument in PCollection using JdbcIO.

My plan is to check if in Mysql table is present value that i get from pubsub ( value listid ).

Here is my code so far, any help will be appreciated.

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages = p.apply(PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
            .fromSubscription("*******"));

    org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<String> messages2 = messages.apply("GetPubSubEvent",
            ParDo.of(new DoFn<PubsubMessage, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    Map<String, String> Map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    PubsubMessage message = c.element();
                    String messageText = new String(message.getPayload(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(messageText);
                    String requestURL = jsonObj.getJSONObject("httpRequest").getString("requestUrl");
                    String query = requestURL.split("\\?")[1];
                    final Map<String, String> querymap = Splitter.on('&').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=")
                            .split(query);
                    JSONObject querymapJson = new JSONObject(querymap);
                    int subscriberid = 0;
                    int listid = 0;
                    int statid = 0;
                    int points = 0;
                    String stattype = "";
                    String requesttype = "";
                    try {
                        subscriberid = querymapJson.getInt("emp_uid");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        listid = querymapJson.getInt("emp_lid");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        statid = querymapJson.getInt("emp_statid");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        stattype = querymapJson.getString("emp_stattype");
                        Map.put("stattype", stattype);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        requesttype = querymapJson.getString("type");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        statid = querymapJson.getInt("leadscore");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                    Map.put("subscriberid", String.valueOf(subscriberid));
                    Map.put("listid", String.valueOf(listid));
                    Map.put("statid", String.valueOf(statid));
                    Map.put("requesttype", requesttype);
                    Map.put("leadscore", String.valueOf(points));
                    Map.put("requestip", jsonObj.getJSONObject("httpRequest").getString("remoteIp"));
                    System.out.print("Hello from message 1");
                    c.output(Map.toString());
                }
            }));

    org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<String> messages3 = messages2.apply("Test",
            ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
                @ProcessElement
                public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    System.out.println(c.element());
                    System.out.print("Hello from message 2");
                }
            }));
    org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection<KV<String, String>> messages23 = messages2.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<String, String>>read()
            .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver",
                    "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/beam"))
            .withQuery("select * from artist").withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>() {
                public KV<String, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                    KV<String, String> kv = KV.of(resultSet.getString("label"), resultSet.getString("name"));
                    return kv;
                }

                @Override
                public KV<String, String> mapRow(java.sql.ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                    KV<String, String> kv = KV.of(resultSet.getString("label"), resultSet.getString("name"));
                    return kv;
                }
            }).withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of())));


    p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Comment: It is unclear what exactly is the problem. Are you getting errors from JdbcIO?

You can look at the integration test example for JdbcIO: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIOIT.java#L47

Maybe unit test can help you as well to get started: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/503029d5ba9f34c7bd08739fd58a6db93cc404b0/sdks/java/io/jdbc/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIOTest.java#L60

Comment: I had hard time to figure out if i can use Java functionallity like connection to DB, Elasticsearch in Dataflow but it is all set now. I just needed to open connection to mysql and elasticsearch for Dataflow. Thanks.